# JSON как вытащить число, которое записано строкой из объекта избегая остальную строку

Tags: javascript, json, discord

```
{
"example": {
    "field": [
       {
         "name": "text",
         "value": "Текущее значение: 123123213124141\n"
       }
    ]
  }
}
```

Как вытащить из value только число?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через регулярку:

```js
const data = JSON.parse(`{
  "example": {
    "field": [
       {
         "name": "text",
         "value": "Текущее значение: 123123213124141"
       }
    ]
  }
}`);
const n = data.example.field[0].value.match(/(\d+)/g);
console.log(n[0]);
```